# Angular2 get FormGroup from children route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

Hi i don't know if what i'm going to ask is possible, but i need to get a FormGroup which is in a dynamic component which is in a child route, i already tried with @ContentChild(FormGroupDirective) but it always is undefined.

i want to avoid the usage of Output events because it will make lost sense to what i'm thinking (a set of widgets which could have a form and the submit button is on the router-outlet component), is on that way because all the widgets have the same behavior.

I'll really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You could emit the FormGroup on instantiation using a service (and subscribe where you need access to it), or if it's a direct decendent you can use the @Output tag and register it with the parent on instantiation.  The parent will have the same reference, so you can perform any operation on it and see it reflect to the child.

Comment: The submit button is on the the router-outlet so there is no way i can listen for the ngSubmit event nor trigger the ngSubmit in the widget, and BTW the widgets are not direct decendents of the router-outlet (here is where my problem comes up), recently i was thinking in a service but i don't know how to trigger the ngSubmit from outside the form

Comment: "The submit button is on the the router-outlet" -- if you update your post with some example code, I may be able to help.